# bootstrap off-canvas how to increase the navigation width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

when using Bootstrap off-canvas template on a phone in portrait orientation. The toggle button slides out the navigation links to around half of the screen

[image]

How can i make the navigation links occupy most of the screen so i can accommodate a larger nav?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

CSS changed to

```
.row-offcanvas-right.active {
    right: 85%; /* 6 columns */
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 85%; /* 6 columns */
  }
```